# Last business day of quarter

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I find the last business day of a quarter? No Sat/Sun. Holiday is fine.

Below gives me the last day of last quarter but I need to find the last business day.

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q') - 1 LAST_DAY_OF_LAST_QTR
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: How do you define "*business day*"?

Comment: I assume they mean the last day that isn't Saturday or Sunday.

Comment: Hint: Date Dimension to the rescue!!!

Comment: @JacobH - 1) What if your company's Quarters don't run January, April, July, October? 2) What if Monday or Friday is both the end of the Quarter and a Holiday? This is one of the beauties of Calendar Tables / Date Dimensions.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/  << That is MS SQL Server, but the concepts are the same.

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing. Calendar tables are great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but this is what I came up with:

Here is what I am assuming about your system:

- Business days are Monday-Friday
- Your first day of the week starts on Sunday in your Oracle database. (This can change based on country/territory settings)

```
with data(r) as
(select 0 r from dual
 union all
 select r+1 from data where r < 6
 )
select max(countingdays) lastbusinessdayofqtr
from (
    select trunc(sysdate, 'Q') - 1 - r countingdays,
           case when to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'Q') - 1 - r,'D') between 2 and 6 then 'Y' else 'N' end BusinessDay
    from data)
    where businessday = 'Y';
```

The with statement generates rows of numbers from 0 to 6. I use those numbers to subtract from the last day of the quarter. Any days between 2 and 6 are Monday - Friday. Finally I take the max date where businessday is 'Y'.

Comment: The reason you had issues is because all parts of the code block should be indented by 4 spaces. The `{}` button does this for you (or highlight and ctrl + k). If you do that the rendering engine assumes that it's a continuation of the bullets... I added a HTML comment to make a break.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I figured it was something to do with the bullets because I can usually just CTRL+K huge blocks at once.

Answer (score 1):

This one is independent from current user `NLS_TERRITORY` and `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` settings:

```
select decode(to_char(trunc(sysdate,'Q')-1,'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american'),
                     'Sat',trunc(sysdate,'Q')-2, -- for saturday
                     'Sun',trunc(sysdate,'Q')-3, -- for sunday
                       trunc(sysdate,'Q')-1  -- for other days
              ) LAST_DAY_OF_LAST_QTR from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a trivial solution, 
if your quarterly last day is sunday, you'll go back for 2 days, or if saturday, you'll go back for 1 day. Then, by the aid of `decode` function, you may use :

```
SQL> col LAST_DAY_OF_LAST_QTR format a22
SQL> select decode(to_char(trunc(sysdate,'Q')-1,'D'),
                         7,trunc(sysdate,'Q')-2, -- for saturday
                         1,trunc(sysdate,'Q')-3, -- for sunday
                           trunc(sysdate,'Q')-1  -- for other days
                  ) LAST_DAY_OF_LAST_QTR from dual;
```

assuming you get value `1 for Sunday`, `7 for saturday`

with respect to your local setting of `nls_date_language` in the following query :

> ```
> select * from
> (
>  select to_char(sysdate-level,'D') day_num, to_char(sysdate-level,'Day') day
>    from dual
>   connect by level <= 7
> ) 
>  order by day_num
> ```

Comment: Note, result of `TRUNC(..., 'D')` depends on current user `NLS_TERRITORY` settings. For example in Europe first day of week is typically Monday, not Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?, 6 is Friday in the query.

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q') - 7, 6) LAST_FRIDAY_OF_LAST_QTR
  FROM DUAL;
```

For the last day, see 3 sample queries below.

17 is Sunday(1) and Saturday(7). If Sunday/Saturday is the last day then it will return the last friday, else return the last day.

```
SELECT DECODE(INSTR('17', TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE('01-JAN-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'Q')-1, 'D'))
               , 0, TRUNC(TO_DATE('01-JAN-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'Q')-1, 
                    NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(TO_DATE('01-JAN-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'Q') - 7, 6)
              )  LAST_BUSINESS_DAY_OF_LAST_QTR
   FROM DUAL;

SELECT DECODE(INSTR('17', TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE('01-AUG-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'Q')-1, 'D'))
               , 0, TRUNC(TO_DATE('01-AUG-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'Q')-1, 
                    NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(TO_DATE('01-AUG-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'Q') - 7, 6)
              )  LAST_BUSINESS_DAY_OF_LAST_QTR
   FROM DUAL;

SELECT DECODE(INSTR('17', TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE('01-OCT-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'Q')-1, 'D'))
               , 0, TRUNC(TO_DATE('01-OCT-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'Q')-1, 
                    NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(TO_DATE('01-OCT-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'Q') - 7, 6)
              )  LAST_BUSINESS_DAY_OF_LAST_QTR
   FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be the last Friday of the quarter?